# Python pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

Please, help someone who knows hot to fix this error:

File "d:\anaconda\lib\site-packages_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks\hook-clr.py", line 40, in 
raise Exception(pyruntime + ' not found')
Exception: Python.Runtime not found

Python version is 3.7.3

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do - which resulted in this error?

Comment: are you trying to create exe ? Can you post full error for us.

Comment: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unl
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_wit
  File "d:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contr
hook-clr.py", line 40, in <module>
    raise Exception(pyruntime + ' not found')
Exception: Python.Runtime not found